# Why are not these two sets subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Why are not these two sets subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

$$
\begin{align}
S_1&=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3
\end{pmatrix}:x_1=x_3\text{ or }x_2=-2x_3
\right\}\\
S_2&=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3
\end{pmatrix}:|x_1|=|x_2|
\right\}
\end{align}
$$
With the first one, I do not understand the `or' part? what does it mean?

Comment: You know what the word "or" means. You use the word "or" in everyday language. Every vector in that set must satisfy one or the other equality, so the set is a union of the set of vectors that satisfy the first equality with the set of vectors that satisfy the second equality. More generally, we teach that "and" and "or" in set-builder notation corresponds to intersection and union. In this problem, geometrically each equality describes a line, and the union of two distinct lines is not itself a line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"or" means union. So in the first example the set consists of two planes which intersect at a line parameterized by $t(2,-1,2)$, $t\in\mathbb{R}$. Geometrically you can see this set is not a subspace since addition will fail. For instance $(1,0,1),(,0,1,-2)$ are in the set ,however their addition $(1,1,-1)$ is not in the set since $x_{1}=1\neq -2=x_{3}$ and $x_{2}=1\neq 2=-2x_{3}$. (Notice how to not be in the set I had to use the "and" connective which is the negation of the "or" connective). The second set is not a subspace since it consists of two planes crossing through the $x_{3}$ axis. Again additivity fails since $(1,-1,0),(1,1,0)$ are in the set but their addition $(1,0,0)$ is not in the set since $|x_{1}|=1\neq 0=|x_{2}|$.